# Android SharedPreferences Force Close on commit in Froyo

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-2.2-froyo

This code seems to work fine on everything except when I emulate it on Froyo. I don't have an actual device running Froyo, so I can't test it on an actual device, but it FC's when it get's to the commit. I even have the code in a try block, so I would think that it should catch an exception instead of force closing.

```
private void getPrefs() {

    boolean dockRespond;
    boolean carDockRespond;
    boolean silenceRinger;

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = settings.edit();

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    dockRespond = prefs.getBoolean("dockRespond", true);
    carDockRespond = prefs.getBoolean("carDockRespond", true);
    silenceRinger = prefs.getBoolean("silenceRinger", false);

    Intent startDock = new Intent(this, DockService.class);

    if(dockRespond)
    {
        //start dock listener service
        startService(startDock);
    }
    else
    {
        //stop dock listener service
        stopService(startDock);
    }

    try
    {
        editor.putBoolean(DOCKRESPONSEGLOBAL, dockRespond);
        editor.putBoolean(CARDOCKRESPONSEGLOBAL, carDockRespond);
        editor.putBoolean(SILENCERINGER, silenceRinger);
        editor.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Exception caught: ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

All of the constants (in all caps) are defined above in the constants area, and as I said before, the code seems to work on any OS version except Froyo. In froyo it FC's on the "editor.commit();" line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace?

Comment: use editor.apply() instead of editor.commit();

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya editor.apply() doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @Shaun Where do I get a stack trace? (Sorry, I'm new with Android development.)

Comment: If your device is plugged into the computer while running, in Eclipse open the DDMS/Logcat perspective and the stacktrace will be all the red text you find when it FCs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. What was happening was that I was putting myself into an endless loop. I had to:

```
settings.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsListener);
```

make my changes, then

```
settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(prefsListener);
```

Not sure why that only created an issue in Froyo. Google must have made a change in the OS to prevent this in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anywhere in your code where you define what editor is? The first line of code that has editor in it is

```
editor = settings.edit();
```

but you never define what 'editor' is

Comment: "settings" and "editor" are also both defined above this, in the global area, then assigned a value here. I actually assign the value in onCreate as well, but figured I'd try to do so here to see if it would help.

This is their definition:

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;